# Why does this recursive tree function work when I don't recursively call "return" inside the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree

I am solving [this problem in Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-right-side-view/). The problem is: Given a binary tree, imagine yourself standing on the right side of it, return the values of the nodes you can see ordered from top to bottom. (Note: I am not asking for help with the logic for solving this algorithm. I am just asking about the code that I wrote while I was solving this problem.)

My question is why does my code work when it is written like this:

```
class Solution:
    def rightSideView(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
        def helper(node, level, output):
            if level == len(output):
                output.append(node.val)
            if node.right:
                helper(node.right, level+1, output)
            if node.left:
                helper(node.left, level+1, output)
            return output
            
        if not root:
            return []
        else:
            return helper(root, 0, [])
```

but not like this:

```
class Solution:
    def rightSideView(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
        def helper(node, level, output):
            if level == len(output):
                output.append(node.val)
            if node.right:
                return helper(node.right, level+1, output)
            if node.left:
                return helper(node.left, level+1, output)
            return output
            
        if not root:
            return []
        else:
            return helper(root, 0, [])
```

I am confused because in other recursive functions it seems that I always have to write `return`.

Comment: Because `helper` is mutating `output`, which then gets returned by the outer method. You can't early return, the two `if` conditions aren't mutually exclusive (both `node.left` and `node.right` could be truth-y).

Comment: It's probably because python passes arrays as address instead of copies, which allows the `helper` function to update the contents of `output` without it having to return it everytime.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ah yes I see that now. Thank you.